# XML create file in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml, elementtree

I ran into a problem and don’t know how to solve it.
I have two types of objects, collection and element, they have many attributes and I need to write it to **XML** like a:

```
<data>
    <collection name="" .../>
        <element name="" link="" .../>
    </collection>
</data>
```

Every collection object has list with elements inside.
So how can I do this with one loop that iterates over collections in a collection list.

Thanks for your answers!

UPD: I just used formatted strings to write markup and this works great for such a simple task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using SimplifiedDoc. You need to install simplified_scrapy before you can use the following code. pip install simplified_scrapy

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req, utils
html = '''
<data>
    <collection name="coll">
        <element name="ele1" link="link1" .../>
        <element name="ele2" link="link2" .../>
    </collection>
</data>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
elements = doc.data.collection.elements
print(elements.name)
```

Result:

```
['ele1', 'ele2']
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a library to handle that, but this might be a bit overkill. If you want to give it a try, check out this official tutorial on the Python site:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

You could also give the elements you want to serialise a toXMLString() method, that generates the representation for this object in XML and returns it as a string.

Call this method in your loop, and write to your file.